# Querying an ethereum contract without ABI, with only input bytes

Tags: transactions, abi, bytes32, deployed-bytecode

I know some transaction has some input bytes to the contract as specified by Etherscan or a mining pool (for instance, [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x722d3ebaaee0dac23d715e90461e307a239670c6e7ab9ab9cad5fd650627c2eb) has input data that looks like 0x000000062de258...9b1d). I know how to deserialize that into json, and I want to send those bytes to another contract. How do I send the identical transaction data, using say ethers with hardhat or geth, without knowing the ABI of any of the contracts involved?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Ethers` than you can create a signer (e.g. [Wallet](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet)) and call [`sendTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-sendTransaction) with the `data` and `to` that you want.

With [hardhat-ethers](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html) you can get all available signers with `await hre.ethers.getSigners()`

You can also do this directly via MetaMask:

[image]

An example where this is done can be found here (at 1:35): https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741